# How can I change global variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, global, var

My html page displays a button that calls a function when it is clicked. I checked to make sure that the button works properly by displaying a message when clicked and it worked. I created this function to change the global varible but when I click another button on my html page to show the value of the varibles the varibles have not changed to the value I set them using my function. Could someone find the problem in my code below?

```
    var a = 5;
    var b = 16;
    var c = 27;

    function reset(){
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    c = 0;
    }
```

My html code to call the function:

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>

   <html>
   <center>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js" > </script>
   <form>
   <input type="button" value="Reset Variables" style="width:250px;height:50px" onclick="reset()" >
   </form>
   </html>
```

Javascript code to show the variables:

```
    function display(){

    document.write("A is equal to " + a + "<br/>");
    document.write("B is equal to " + b + "<br/>");
    document.write("C is equal to " + c );

}
```

Html to display the variables

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>

   <html>
   <center>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js" > </script>
   <form>
   <input type="button" value="Show Variables" style="width:250px;height:50px" onclick="display()" >
   </form>
   </html>
```

Comment: Can you show us the function called when you click the button?

Comment: Is that all the code? How are they called from the butons?

Comment: You need to include more of your code.

Comment: Is the JS you've shown contained in game.js? The snippet you've shown doesn't have a problem that would stop the variables being updated. Please show the code that _uses_ the variables, that might be where the problem is.

Comment: The code where you show the values of the variables is missing - this is key to solving this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the function name to reset_vars or anything else. reset() is in-built DOM function used for resetting forms.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp

There won't be any conflict when a global variable is used inside a function unless a local variable is defined. in such case, use window.variable_name to access global variable.

Answer (score 0):

That can`t work, because you are asserting that variables in function scope. But your variables are currently stored in global scope (window), so this code will work:

```
var a = 5;
function reset() {
    console.log(window.a); // 5
    window.a = 10;
}
reset();
console.log(a); // 10
```

Comment: After using this code in my javascript function, it still will not display the changed variables when I click on the button to display variables

Comment: Michael you don't need to access globals via the window object (unless the globals are shadowed by local variables of the same names).